# Elasticsearch Kafka Connector - setting index based on message value

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have messages coming through a Kafka topic in the following format:

```
{"elasticsearch_index": "index_1", "first_name": "Jane"}
{"elasticsearch_index": "index_2", "first_name": "John"}
```

Note that each message contains the desired Elasticsearch index that we would like to route the record to. Is it possible to use Confluent's Elasticsearch Kafka Connector to route these records to the appropriate index name (e.g. whatever is listed under the `elasticsearch_index` key)?

It doesn't look like the Single Message Transforms (SMT) supports this behavior currently, but maybe I am misreading. Any info will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Write your own Transform using the [Single Message Transform API](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Transformation.html)
2. Use KSQL (or Kafka Streams) to route the messages to required topics first, and then use the new (Apache Kafka 1.1) regex capabilities to land those topics to Elasticsearch from Kafka Connect.